# How to create two objects inside one create controller method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I need to create two objects: `sale` and `organization`. This happens inside `sales_controller`.

For brevity's sake, the models and their attributes are:

```
sale
  amount (integer)
  organization_id (uuid)

organization
  name (string)

sale belongs_to organization
organization has_many sales
```

[image: Sales Form]

That is what the `sales new` should look like. It has an input for sales, which user will enter, and it also has an input for Organization name, which user will input. Upon submission, user will have created a new sale (plus created a new organization, associated to that sale).

I am trying to figure out what is the best practice for `create` method inside sales_controller.

```
  def create
    @sale = Sale.new(sale_params) #assume sale_params permits organization_id and amount
    @organization = Organization.create(params[:name])
    #@sale.organization_id = @organization.id
    if @sale.save
      render json: @sale
    else
      render json: sale, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

`@organization = Organization.create(...)` does not feel right. Is there a way to do multiple object submission the "Rails"-way?

Comment: An old article but the following should help: https://webuild.envato.com/blog/creating-form-objects-with-activemodel-and-virtus/
You don't actually need Virtus but the article will give you the gist of wrapping up the validations etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you may already have created an Organization on a previous sale you could use:

`@organization = Organization.find_or_create_by(name: params[:name])`

and then continue by associating the sale.organization_id. You will need to have a uniqueness constraint on Organization.name as well.